# Though the mail() returns true, email is not received.Is there anything wrong with the configuration?

Tags: php, windows, email, xampp

Following is the configuration in `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` respectively :

```
[mail function]
sendmail_path = ""\"E:\Installed_Apps\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t""
mail.add_x_header = Off

[sendmail]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=my_gmail_address
auth_password=my_xxxxxx
pop3_server=
pop3_username= 
pop3_password=
force_recipient=
hostname=
```

And I try to send email as :

```
<?php
$sent = mail('to_someone@hotmail.com','Message sent from XAMPP','Hey ! I just sent you a message using XAMPP');
if($sent) {
    echo "Mail sent successfully";
}else {
    echo "Sending failed";
}
```

I always get `true` for `$sent` but there is no email received at the above address. What could be the reason for this ? Is there anything wrong with the configuration file ?

***Note :***
*I uploaded `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` @ [github](https://github.com/suhailgupta03/php.git) and I am running mercury on 25*

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100659/no-mail-received-in-inbox-with-xampp-1-8-0-mercurymail-and-mail

Comment: Have you read the notes and comments on the documentation page? http://php.net/mail

Comment: From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) "It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, **it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination**. "

Comment: check whether smtp server runs as windows services

Answer (score 1):

You are actively setting it to use `mailtodisk.exe` which is a program that simply takes the e-mail and saves it to a folder - it never attempts to send the e-mail at all, it is simply a tool for checking that your e-mails look right.

From the docs regarding `sendmail_path`:

> If set, smtp, smtp_port and sendmail_from are ignored and the
>   specified command is executed.

Try commenting out `sendmail_path` and check that you have a SMTP server running on your computer on port 25.

Comment: I have actually commented out `mailtodisk.exe` and uncommented `"\"E:\Installed_Apps\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"`

Comment: Have you checked the `sendmail.log` file (should be in the same directory as sendmail.exe). It may reveal why the e-mails are not being sent. As mentioned, PHP will in a lot of cases report "True" as long as sendmail takes care of the input, whether it gets sent or not.

Comment: I didn't find `sendmail.log`

Comment: Also `mercury` is running on `25`

Comment: I have uploaded `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` @ [github](https://github.com/suhailgupta03/php.git). Is there any thing wrong with it ?

Comment: Try changing the sendmail_path to `sendmail_path = "E:\Installed_Apps\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"`

Comment: Maybe you just can't send email via xampp!! You need a web server.