# Mercury: sending email from localhost

Tags: email, mercury-mta

I configured my Mercury (on local PC with Windows 7 professional) step-by-step following http://www.open-emr.org/wiki/index.php/Mercury_Mail_Configuration_in_Windows, using smtp.gmail.com as external server. I then sent a test email to my gmail from Mercury, and the Mercury core process window showed "Mon 01, 10:50:08: Job MG000001: from postmaster@localhost (local) .... to xxxx@gmail.com (non-local)-OK". But the Mercury SMTP client (relay version) window showed "Faild. Error FF servicing queue job." I saw this error message being repeated (Mercury tried to re-send the email).

I tried to gether more error information but the Mercury logs (XAMPP Control penal) was empty.
Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: I changed SMTP port from 25 (normal) to 465 (SSL encryption) and it worked. Does any one know why? Also, port 465 is not listed for Mercury on XAMPP Control panel (port 25 is).Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as yours and I came out with this solution.

Follow the answer in this link: 
[No mail received in inbox with XAMPP 1.8.0, MercuryMail and mail()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100659/no-mail-received-in-inbox-with-xampp-1-8-0-mercurymail-and-mail)

And then go to

***Mercury under MercuryS -> Connection Control -> Uncheck "Do not Permit SMTP relaying to non-local mail"***

Hope it helps :)